# Asynchronous file saving

Tags: .net, file-io, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

In my program (.net framework 4) i want release asynchronous file saving. 
What i must use?
The **Task** class or **BeginWrite** method?
What's the difference? And what is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Task.Factory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321543) to wrap the `BeginWrite`/`EndWrite` method pairs into a `Task<T>`.  This will let you use the TPL to write asynchronous code, while still using the underlying asynchronous IO methods.